# Can collaborative filtering be used to recommend events?

Tags: algorithm

I've been reading up on collaborative filtering for building recommendation engines and the examples tend to be around things like movies where the user rates a movie they've seen which is then used to find other movies they might like.

But in the context of an event this seems to make less sense, asking a user to rate an event isn't particularly helpful as they can only rate it after they've seen it and assuming it's a one off event that has by that point finished you can no longer recommend it to anyone.

I know one option for that is to assign a rating of 1 if they buy a ticket for something and leave it as 0 if they haven't. But that's not ideal either as someone might by a ticket for something, hate it and not want to be recommended anything similar. Plus it also assumes you know when the user has bought tickets for something which might not always be possible.

So is there a good way of doing using collaborative filtering for events and if not are there any other algorithms better suited?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would dismiss the way you described movie rankings altogether...but maybe you need to refine the data you collect.

It seems your basic approach is to recommend based on "Other people who liked X also liked Y".  Well, X and Y don't have to be a precise thing.  Maybe if you rate X, the rating is somehow applied to subcomponents of X.  In the case of a movie this might be the starring actor, the director, and genre.  In the case of a night-time show this might be the type of act and performer.

So, even though your users might rate the event, you could recommend based on those "tags" or sub-components.  E.g. "other people who liked ComedianA also like ComedianB," or "many people who liked ComedianA are going to see ComedianB."

Comment: Thanks for the response it's an interesting approach but wouldn't it make it hard to recommend things that don't necessarily have any subcomponents in common? For example if an event is a Mozart concert and another event is a film screening of Amadeus, people who go to one might be interested in going to the other. If the concert has already happened then I need some subcomponent to link it to the film screening and the only way I can see of doing that is with some kind of tagging system. But then your recommendation system is constrained by how well you can tag everything.